# Using Swift Mailer with smtp on Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, smtp, symfony4, swiftmailer

I installed Swift Mailer on Symfony 4 to send a registration email for new users. What I noticed is that it works fine when I use my Gmail account to send emails, but it doesn't work when I use my Outlook.

So after reading the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html#configuration), I set the MAILER_URL on my .env file like this

```
>  MAILER_URL=smtp://localhost:25?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=*****%40live.com&password=******
```

I also used :

```
>  MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp-mail.outlook.com:25/encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=*******%40live.com&password=********
```

I have changed the port from 25 to 587 to 465 and none of those worked either.

This is the method where I call the mailer :

```
public function sendMail($subject, $fromEmail, $toEmail, $emailTemplate, $argumentsArray, $emailType, $imgPath)
{
    $message = $this->setBasicEmailMessage($subject, $fromEmail, $emailTemplate, $argumentsArray, $emailType, $imgPath);
    $message->setTo($toEmail);
    $this->mailer->send($message);
}


private function setBasicEmailMessage($subject, $fromEmail, $emailTemplate, $argumentsArray, $emailType, $imgPath)
{
    $message = (new \Swift_Message($subject))->setFrom($fromEmail);
    $img = $message->embed(\Swift_Image::fromPath($imgPath));
    $argumentsArray['img'] = $img;
    $message->setBody(
        $this->templating->render(
            $emailTemplate,
            $argumentsArray
        ),
        $emailType
    );

    return $message;
}
```

And this is my swiftmailer.yaml:

```
swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

The code doesn't raise an exception but the email never makes it to the users.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Put send function in try and catch block you will get definitely any clue:

```
try {
   $this->mailer->send($message);

 } catch (\Swift_RfcComplianceException $e) {

            echo "\nException :: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: That doesn't work because the code doesn't raise an exception